# Make Textbox to accept values built of 4 digit blocks

Tags: c#

I want to have a textbox that whenever you reached the 4th digit it would add a space automatically and it should do that everytime the 4th digit is inserted.

Ex. 4565 6585 6599 5656 ...

I have tried something like this but most likely it is wrong:

```
textBox2.Text.ToString(new NumberFormatInfo() { NumberGroupSizes = new[] { 4 }, NumberGroupSeparator = " " });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe an idea to create 4 textboxes, limited with 4 characters Max. That is a common design pattern as well.

Comment: why not use maskedTextBox

Comment: @Max it is fairly common, but I'd argue also bad UX. Mouse drivers (those who use the mouse primarily) are slown down significantly moving box to box to box.

Comment: @AustinFrench I agree, although pretty much users are aware of the tab button. The 4 textboxes do inform the user better, what to expect as well

Comment: Which UI technology you use? Winforms? Wpf or Asp.Net? Whatever it may be, you'll be having `MaskedTextBox` I guess. Use it.

Comment: I don't see the point of using 4 textboxes when I only need one and the user should insert as many pairs of 4 as he would like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [`MaskedTextBox` control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with a mask like this:

```
txt.Mask = "0000 0000 0000 0000";
```

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a summary of the syntax.

Comment: I've updated the syntax link to msdn docs. I hope you don't mind :)

Comment: I will give it a try and comeback with an answer but it should do the work. I will also take a look at the link you provided. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using JavaScript or jQuery.

Please look at this SO entry on "[Credit Card Input Form Using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677247/credit-card-input-form-using-jquery)".

Comment: He did not mention that it's a webapplication.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Neither he mentioned it is a winforms application.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: by experience i know that most if not all people who don't mention the technology mean winforms. But you're right, OP should clarify that.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I've asked the OP about the UI technology. Let him confirm.

Comment: it is not a web application but a winform ....it is a tool that I am using to manage a database